# How get variables in other classes?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I want to access my variable $hello in my model.php file, how i do that ??

## contollers/controller.php

```
class {

 public function hello() {

  $hello = "Hello world";

 }

}
```

## model/model.php

```
class {

 public function helloworld() {

  echo $hello;

 }

}
```

I want to get the variable $hello...

Comment: Pass it as a parameter when you call the function

Comment: Deleted my answer as I thought this was in the same class. I'd pass it as watcher mentioned ^^

Comment: Why? Can you give some context to understand your class structure and what you are trying to achieve? This looks not like MVC at all, except the class names.

Answer (score 2):

In order to retrieve data from one object to another, you should create methods that return the particular data.

```
class controller{
    private $hello;

    public function setHello(){
        $this->hello = 'hi';
    }

    public function getHello(){
        return $this->hello;
    }
 }

 class model{

     public function helloWorld(){
         $controller = new controller();
         $controller->setHello();
         $hello = $controller->getHello();

     }

 }
```

Also note that its not usual to initiate controllers from models, take a look at MVC for example. So basicly in above example the model should be the controller and visa versa.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a variable from a *class* (as you said), then you're looking for the `static` keyword:

```
class Controller {
    static $hello = "Hello world";
}

class Model {
    public function helloworld() {
        echo Controller::$hello;
    }
}

$model = new Model();
$model->helloworld();
```

If you meant "I want to create a `Controller` object and have a `Model` object be able to read a message from that controller, you're looking for this:

```
class Controller {
    public function hello() {
        return "Hello world";
    }
}

class Model {
    public function helloworld($controller) {
        echo $controller->hello();
    }
}

$controller = new Controller();
$model = new Model();

$model->helloworld($controller);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your classes doesn't have name?

In your **controller.php**

```
<?PHP
class Controller{
    public static function hello () {
        $hello = "Hello World!";
        #when you call a function, you need to say what it must return!
        return $hello;
    }
}
?>
```

In your **model.php**

```
<?php
class Model extends Controller {
   public static function helloworld() {
     #call the function inside the controller class. class::function();
     $text = Controller::hello();
     #tell what to do, you can use echo or return.
     return $text;
   }
}
?>
```

In your **index.php**

```
<?PHP
include "controller.php";
include "model.php";
#include everything you need

#use class:function();
echo Model::helloworld();
```